# Failed to compile error when using typescript, react and webpack and starting with yarn start

Tags: typescript, webpack, yarnpkg

when using `awesome-typescript-loader@3.2.1`, `webpack@3.4.1` and `typescript@2.4.2`. I keep getting a `Failed to compile` error on the console. The errors usually vary from *unable to file @types* under the `node_modules/@types` folder to specific files in my project.

I have tried deleting `yarn.lock` file and yarn installing everything, but it keeps coming up.

```
// error about @types

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/react-router/node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:3620:13
    TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'output' must be of type 'DetailedHTMLProps<OutputHTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>, HTMLElement>', but here has type 'DetailedHTMLProps<OutputHTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>, HTMLElement>'.


// error about project files.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/index.tsx:29:7
    TS2605: JSX element type 'ConnectedRouter<{}>' is not a constructor function for JSX elements.
  Types of property 'render' are incompatible.
    Type '() => ReactNode' is not assignable to type '{ (): false | Element; (): ReactNode; (): ReactNode; (): ReactNode; (): ReactNode; (): ReactNode;...'.
      Type 'ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'false | Element'.
        Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'false | Element'.
```

My current `tsconfig.json` file

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "target": "ES6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "paths": {            // <= when I add this 'paths' object the errors disappear, but I cannot find my app files `TS2307: Cannot find module 'containers/Listing/reducer'`
      "*": [
          "node_modules/*",
          "node_modules/@types/*"
      ]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/global.d.ts",
    "./src/index.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/*.test.ts*"
  ]
}
```

*package.json*

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "myapp",
  "keywords": [
  ],
  "license": "",
  "engines": {
    "npm": ">=3",
    "node": ">=6"
  },
  "main": "./dist/main.js",
  "types": "./dist/index.d.ts",
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "build": "npm run build:full",
    "build:base": "webpack --config ./config/webpack.config.js --color",
    "build:full": "npm run test && npm run build:clean && npm run build:base",
    "build:clean": "rimraf ./dist",
    "start": "node ./scripts/server.js",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/lodash.orderby": "^4.6.3",
    "axios": "0.16.2",
    "babel-polyfill": "6.23.0",
    "domify": "^1.4.0",
    "history": "4.6.3",
    "immutable": "3.8.1",
    "lodash.orderby": "^4.6.0",
    "query-string": "5.0.0",
    "react": "15.5.1",
    "react-dom": "15.5.1",
    "react-redux": "5.0.5",
    "react-router-dom": "4.1.2",
    "react-router-redux": "5.0.0-alpha.6",
    "redux": "3.7.2",
    "redux-immutable": "4.0.0",
    "redux-saga": "0.15.4",
    "reselect": "3.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/enzyme": "2.8.4",
    "@types/jest": "18.1.1",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.86",
    "@types/node": "8.0.31",
    "@types/react": "15.0.39",
    "@types/react-dom": "0.14.23",
    "@types/react-hot-loader": "3.0.1",
    "@types/react-redux": "4.4.47",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "4.0.7",
    "@types/react-router-redux": "5.0.4",
    "@types/redux-immutable": "3.0.34",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "3.2.1",
    "babel-core": "6.25.0",
    "babel-loader": "6.4.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs": "6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-env": "1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "6.24.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "2.1.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "2.29.0",
    "image-webpack-loader": "3.3.1",
    "jest-bamboo-formatter": "^1.0.1",
    "lodash": "4.17.4",
    "rimraf": "2.6.1",
    "sass-loader": "6.0.6",
    "tslint": "4.5.1",
    "tslint-loader": "3.5.3",
    "typescript": "2.4.2",
    "webpack": "3.4.1",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "1.11.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.6.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.18.0",
    ...rest_of_dependencies
  }
}
```

Comment: What is your package.json?

Comment: @rm4 just added the `package.json` as an **EDIT**